# How to run Selenium Java tests with TestNG programmatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, automated-tests, selenium-rc, testng

I am using Selenium RC with Java using TestNG as Test Framework. I'm using Eclipse as IDE. I want to invoke TestNG from my own program very easily. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TheStijn gives a few good directions, although TestMethodWorker() is internal so you shouldn't use it.

Based on the question, I'm not even sure the original poster is trying to launch TestNG in a separate process, so the API documentation might be what you're looking for:

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically

Comment: My following code is worked nicely:
TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] {LoginAuthentication.class});
testng.addListener(tla);
testng.run();
com.beust.testng.TestNG; TestNG is deprecated. Is there any alternative way?

Comment: Use org.testng.TestNG instead of com.beust.TestNG

Comment: you can follow this blog as well http://dharshanaw.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-execute-testng-tests.html

Comment: I tried the snippet however I get a NoClassDefFoundError while trying to run it , do I have to do anything except  cretaing my test class and a test method in it .

Answer (score 8):

My following code in java works nicely:

```
@Test
public void testTestNGProgramatically(){
TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] {LoginAuthentication.class, GmailSigninSignout.class});
testng.addListener(tla);
testng.run(); 
}
```

You can get the details explanation by visiting the following URL:

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically

Comment: In my above code: TestNG is deprecated in line "TestNG testng = new TestNG();" . What is the alternative of TestNG class?

Comment: Use `org.testng.TestNG`, not `com.beust.TestNG` (the one you are probably importing).

Comment: @CedricBeust: Thanks a lot. Yes, I have imported org.testng.TestNG instead of com.beust.TestNG and OK now

Comment: above code executes multiple classes parallel, how to avoid [parallel execution?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG, this will however require you to write an xml suite for your tests like:

```
<suite name="Default suite">
  <test verbose="2" name="Default test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com...service.UserServiceImplTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Another entry point might be new org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker(...).run() but you'll have to look at the code to determine the constructor args you need to set.

Perhaps other, more convenient entry points are available depending on your needs; I suggest to launch some test in debug mode, put a breakpoint in your test and go down the stack.

Comment: Yes, this is the content of xml file. So, build.xml file is run by using either eclipse or Ant