# Eliminating the need for testng.xml when running Java unit tests in TestNG

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

I find the need to maintain and edit testng.xml despite the availability of annotations as a limitation of TestNG. Is it possible to either automate the generation of testng.xml, or completely eliminate the need for it while running unit tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From testng.org documentation: "You can invoke TestNG from your own programs very easily":

```
TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { Run2.class });
testng.addListener(tla);
testng.run();
```

This example creates a TestNG object and runs the test class Run2. It also adds a TestListener.

**Ref:**

> You can read more about it Here: [http://testng.org/](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically) 
>  Here is
>   one [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457983) Discussion on the simillar topic
>  A working example
>   class on [Github](https://github.com/Chandan-Nayak/stackoverflow-files/blob/master/RunTestNG.java)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.